# Can't seem to execute code against an unmanaged package

Tags: apex, package, compile-error

I'm relatively new to using unmanaged packages and have run into a (likely) simple issue. I'm currently attempting to execute some anonymous code against a package that I installed today, however I am getting hung up with the following error:

[image: Error Message]

The IDE appears to recognize the objects (in this case `GraphQLNode`) as Intellisense is working in both VSCode and in the SF Developer console. I get the same error in the Developer Console in SF. I can see that the classes exist in Salesforce as well.

Any thoughts as to what might be going on? I'm pretty sure I'm missing something super fundamental here.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You appear to be missing a semicolon after `new GraphQLNode('orders')` (unless you are chaining additional methods like you would with a "fluent interface"). Errors returned by anonymous apex can be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

D'oh! I was missing a parentheses later in the statement. Sorry - disregard!